# How to randomly change position after animation complete?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create an effect that simulates the twinkling of stars in the sky.

I have achieved it to a certain degree as such: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vanmk1ec/2/)

My JS to create the stars:

```
    var limit=50,
body = document.body;
spread={
    start:function(){
        for (var i=0; i<=limit; i++){
            var star=this.newStar();
            var randomD = Math.random()*30;
            var randomDelay = randomD.toString() + "s";
            star.style.top=this.rand()*90+"%";
            star.style.left=this.rand()*98+"%";
            star.style.animationDelay= randomDelay;
            body.appendChild(star);

        };
    },
    rand:function(){
        return Math.random();
    },
    newStar:function(){
        var d = document.createElement('div');
        d.innerHTML= '<figure class="star"></figure>';
        return  d.firstChild;
    }
};
spread.start();
```

However, I want to randomize the "star" position after it's finished it's animation.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using both `Math.random()` and the wrapper `this.rand()` in your `start` function?

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the `animationiteration` event on the element which fires when the animation loops.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/19zzj9af/1/)

```
spread={
    start:function(){
        for (var i=0; i<=limit; i++){
            var star=this.newStar();
            var randomD = Math.random()*30;
            var randomDelay = randomD.toString() + "s";
            this.randomizeStar(star);
            star.style.animationDelay= randomDelay;
            star.addEventListener("animationiteration",
                    this.randomizeStar.bind(null, star));
            body.appendChild(star);

        };
    },
    rand:function(){
        return Math.random();
    },
    newStar:function(){
        var d = document.createElement('div');
        d.innerHTML= '<figure class="star"></figure>';
        return  d.firstChild;
    },
    randomizeStar:function(star){
        star.style.top=Math.random()*90+"%";
        star.style.left=Math.random()*98+"%";
    }
};
```

You will need to tweak the animation a little so that the animation ends on `opacity:0`, but the demo clearly shows that the stars are moving.

---

Some tips and comments on your code:

- Just use `Math.random()` instead of creating a `rand` function on `spread`, it doesn't add much.
- The code will be cleaner if you encapsulate the star creation and randomization logic within a `Star` prototype.